# Query to return distinct values in fields containing string across multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

The following query looks for fields within a db that contain '%string%' and returns them in a table with 5 columns; Schema, Table, Number of fields containing desired string in title of field within table, number of rows in table, and finally the field names.

```
SELECT s.name schemaName
    , t.name tabName
    , COUNT(c.name) OVER (PARTITION BY t.name ORDER BY t.name) totalColsWithString
    , rc.row_count
    , c.name colName
FROM sys.all_columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON (t.object_id = c.object_id)
JOIN sys.schemas s ON (s.schema_id = t.schema_id)
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT o.name
        , ddps.row_count
    FROM sys.indexes i
    JOIN sys.objects o ON (i.object_id = o.object_id)
    JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ddps ON (i.object_id = ddps.object_id AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id)
    WHERE i.index_id < 2 AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
) rc ON (rc.name = t.name)
WHERE c.name LIKE '%String%'
    AND row_count <> 0;
```

What I now want is a field that shows the number of distinct values in those fields which contain 'string' in the title (in all the columns returned in above query).

Does MS SQL Server store any info about distinct values in fields? Can it be made to?

Comment: May be to simple an answer, but could you not just use COUNT(DISTINCT c.name)

Comment: that would require the FROM clause to contain the respective table, which the above query doesn't (I'm getting all the info above from the system tables).

Comment: I see, you want the number of distinct values in the columns with a name that contains String. That is probably going to be difficult without resorting to executing SQL strings to retrieve that information. I do not believe that the number of distinct values is stored in the sys database.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

You actually should consider to run 2 queries in that case. Or use subqueries, which may cause performance issues at a big dataset. Subqueries could look like this

```
SELECT [...], 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_columns c2 WHERE c2.name= c.name) AS totalcolswithstring
FROM [...]
```

I set up a fiddle for you [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/473be7/2)

Comment: afaik I can't query the field itself from the sys tables. I want this field to be appended to the above query, as there could potentially be hundreds of fields returned who's name contains 'string'.

Comment: You actually should consider to run 2 queries in that case. Or use subqueries, which may cause performance issues at a big dataset.
Subqueries could look like this `SELECT [...], (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.all_columns c WHERE c.name = '%string%' GROUP BY c.name) AS totalcolswithstring`

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. That will return a single, repeated value that represents a count of fields with '%string%' in the name. I'm looking for the number of distinct values within each of those fields within their respective tables.

Comment: No this isn't quite what I'm looking for either. That's returning distinct field names within the fields list (all_columns) with that column header. What I want is distinct VALUES in the underlying column.

Comment: Its basicly the same, just change from name to value.

Comment: Also i would suggest you to maybe update and form your question more clearly.